# A fair $6$-sided die was rolled $10$ times. Find the probability you rolled exactly two $2$s and exactly two $5$s.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> A fair $6$-sided die was rolled $10$ times. Find the probability you rolled exactly two $2$s and exactly two $5$s.

I know the standard way to calculate this, but wasn't sure why another approach - stars and bars - cannot be applied. If we fix the two $2$s and $5$s to their respective boxes and arrange the rest, we have $nCr(10+6-1-2-2, 6-1)$ ways; If we use stars and bars to calculate the total number of results, we have $nCr(10+6-1, 6-1)$. Setting the former as the numerator and the latter as denominator gives a probability larger than the answer. Why is this the case?

Comment: When you examine the two answers, please resolve the following question, either in your answer, or with a comment:  Did you intend the $x_i$ variable to be the number of dice that showed the number $i$, or did you intend that the $x_i$ variable represented the number of *positions* between two of the $4$ rolls that represented the $2$ 2's and $2$ 5's?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The outcomes counted by "stars and bars" are not equally likely to occur.  There is only one way to obtain a $1$ on every die.  However, there are
$$\binom{10}{2}\binom{8}{2}\binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{2}2!$$
ways to obtain two ones, two twos, two threes, two fours, one five, and one six.  Consequently, if we use "stars and bars", we cannot simply divide the number of favorable outcomes by the number of outcomes in our sample space since those outcomes are not equally likely to occur.

**Addendum:**  Let's examine the standard approach more carefully.

Since there are $6$ possible outcomes for each of the $10$ rolls, there are $6^{10}$ sequences of rolls in our sample space.  These sequences specify not only how many times each number occurs but also where the numbers appear in the sequence of rolls.

For the favorable cases in which exactly two twos and exactly two fives occurs, two of the ten positions in the sequence are filled by the twos, two of the remaining eight positions in the sequence are filled by the fives, and there are four possible outcomes for each of the other six rolls, which gives
$$\binom{10}{2}\binom{8}{2}4^6$$
favorable outcomes.

Consequently, the probability of obtaining exactly two twos and exactly two fives in ten rolls of a fair die is
$$\frac{\dbinom{10}{2}\dbinom{8}{2}4^6}{6^{10}}$$

When we use "stars and bars" to count the outcomes, we lose information since "stars and bars" counts how many times each number occurs but not where those numbers occur in the sequence.  Therefore, it should not be surprising that we do not get the same result using "stars and bars" as we do when counting sequences of outcomes.

As noted above, the specific reason we do not use "stars and bars" is that the outcomes it counts are not equally likely to occur.  When we calculate probabilities by dividing the number of favorable outcomes by the total number of outcomes, we do so under the assumption that each outcome in our sample space is equally likely to occur.

Comment: See my answer.  I am defining the Stars and Bars variables to be the sizes of each of the $5$ regions created by the $4$ *Stars*, which are represented by the $2$ 2's and $2$ 5's.

Comment: I have to give you +1: for **telepathy**.  How you could infer that the OP's variable $x_i$ represents the number of dice rolls that came up $i$ is beyond me.

Answer (score 1):

Although a somewhat offbeat approach, Stars and Bars can be used to solve the problem.

You have $10$ slots, $4$ of which are going to be taken up by $2$ 2's and $2$ 5's.  You can construe these as *Stars*.  You will then have $6$ *Bars* that are divided into $5$ regions, by the $4$ Stars.

So, you compute the number of solutions to

$$x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_5 = 6. \tag1 $$

(1) above has $~\displaystyle \binom{6 + [5-1]}{5-1} = \binom{10}{4}~$ solutions.

Now, for each solution, there are $4$ possibilities for each of the *bars*.  So, this results in a factor of
$\left(4^6\right).$

Further, for each solution, there are $~\displaystyle \binom{4}{2}$ ways of selecting which $2$ of the $4$ *Stars* will be 2's, instead of 5's.

So, in computing the *combinatoric probability fraction* of

$$\frac{N\text{(umerator)}}{D\text{(enominator)}},$$

where $D = 6^{(10)},$ you end with

$$ N = \binom{10}{4} \times \binom{4}{2} \times (4)^6 = \frac{10!}{(6!)(4!)} \times \frac{4!}{(2!)(2!)} \times (4)^6 = \frac{10!}{(6!)(2!)(2!)} \times (4)^6.$$

Alternatively, in the standard approach,

- You have to select $2$ slots for the 2's : factor of $\displaystyle \binom{10}{2} = \frac{10!}{(2!)(8!)}.$
- You then have to select $2$ slots for the 5's : factor of $\displaystyle \binom{8}{2} = \frac{8!}{(2!)(6!)}.$
- You then have to select the number of ways of filling the remaining $6$ positions : factor of $(4)^6.$

$$N = \frac{10!}{(8!)(2!)} \times \frac{8!}{(6!)(2!)} \times (4)^6 = \frac{10!}{(6!)(2!)(2!)} \times (4)^6.$$

Comment: The question was why using "stars and bars" does not give the right probability.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Right.  However, since I couldn't follow his analysis, I wasn't sure if he was trying my approach or yours.  If he intended your approach, then your answer nailed it.  If instead, he intended my approach, then he simply made an analytical mistake in how to use my approach.  His answer focused on *fixing* the $2$'s and $5$'s, so I presumed that he was concerned about positioning the $2$'s and $5$'s.  As I say, I wasn't able to follow his analysis.

Comment: Upon rereading the OP's approach, I realize that the OP did not take into account which rolls were $2$s, which rolls were $5$s, and counted all $10$ rolls rather than distributing the $1$s, $3$s, $4$s, and $6$s among the remaining six rolls.  The OP's analysis does not make sense, which is why you could not follow it.  Consequently, your inclusion of the standard approach provides a useful service.